# R: plot adding a vertical line at the beginning of each January

Tags: r

I have a daily series in a dataframe from 2015 to present of working days (excludes Sat, Sun):

```
df <- df[, c("Date","y")]
```

I can plot a chart:

plot(df$Date,df$y, type="l")

I can also plot vertical lines:

abline (v= x)

But how can I plot a vertical line for the first January date of each year in the series (this may be different from 01 Jan).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it, you just need a way to determine all the first January dates, then pass a vector of those dates as `x` in

```
abline(v=x)
```

lubridate and dplyr provide nice ways to figure this out.

```
# fake data: a sample of dates (in order) and a cumulative series
set.seed(123)
n <- 200
dat <- data.frame(
  Date = sort(sample(seq(from=as.Date('2015-01-01'), 
                         to=as.Date('2018-01-01'), 
                         by='day'),
                     n)
              ),
  y = cumsum(runif(n, min = -10, max=10)))

# load libraries and add flag for first jan dates
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dat <- dat %>%
  # ensure it's sorted by date
  arrange(Date) %>%
  # group by year and month
  group_by(yr = year(Date), mth = month(Date)) %>%
  # flag each first January row
  mutate(first_jan_row = mth ==1 & row_number()==1)
```

Now you can plot them:

```
# your plot
plot(dat$Date, dat$y, type='l')
# ablines on all first jan dates
abline(v=dat$Date[dat$first_jan_row])
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much.