# Semi-annual data (time series)

Tags: r, time-series

I have data that I downloaded from https://stats.bis.org/statx/srs/tseries/OTC_DERIV/H.H.A.A.5J.A.5J.A.TO1.TO1.A.A.3.C?t=d5.2&c=&p=20201&i=63.8 which I plotted but the graph somehow not descriptive enough for me.

I would like to a margin line corresponding to a year on x-axis, so that it can allow me to descript the pattern.

```
library(tidyverse)
OTCData <- read.csv("~/Research Data/All.csv")
DataDate<-as.Date(OTCData$DATE1, format="%m/%d/%Y")
class(DataDate)
OTCGrossCreditExposure = ts(data = OTCData$GrossCreditExposure, frequency = 6, 
                            start=c(1998,6), end=c(2020,06)) 
OTCAllData=cbind(OTCNotional,OTCGrossCreditExposure,OTCGrossMarketValue)
plot(OTCGrossCreditExposure, 
     lwd=2, 
     ylab="Gross Credit Exposure in USD ($)", 
     xlab="Years", main="OTC Gross Credit Exposure",
     col = "red",
     pch=14, 
     font.axis = 1,                    # Change axis font to bold italic
     col.axis = "black"             # Set the color of the axis
     
) 
grid(nx = 44, ny=10, lty=1, col=gray(.9))                                   # add a grid
```

[image: This the output of the code above and I would like the margin on x-axis to represent a year or semi-annual data]

Comment: can you explain what you mean by margin line a bit more? you mean a vertical line for each year?

Comment: @tlhenvironment Yes, I mean vertical line for each year

Comment: please share your dataset with dput(),
i think you can use the abline(v = ...) function, and you can also look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740187/r-plot-adding-a-vertical-line-at-the-beginning-of-each-january

Comment: @tlhenvironment DATE = structure(
        c(23L, 1L, 24L),
        .Label = c(
          "12/31/1998",
          "12/31/1999", ),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      NotionalAmounts = c(72106521.77, 80276622.05, 81420274.61),
      GrossCreditExposure = c(1202805L, 1328580L, 1119372L),
      GrossMarketValues = c(2562152.803, 3209463.957, 2609693.198)
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, 3L),
    class = "data.frame"